# Upgrading to Idris v 1.0 with Cabal?

Tags: cabal, idris

Given:

```
$idris -v
0.99
```

I would like to upgrade to version 1. However, I blindly tried to upgrade by running `cabal install idris` to see this output:

```
$cabal install idris
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
idris-1.0
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

So, it appears that I've already installed `idris` version 1, but I'm not using it, per the `idris -v` output?

How can I use Idris v1 given my situation?

Comment: Add idris symlink to `/usr/bin`:

`/root/.cabal/bin/idris`

Comment: Also, add line to end of your `.bashrc` file. Something like, `export PATH="/root/.cabal/bin:$PATH"` Depending on where `.cabal` dir is located.

Comment: Thanks, @noobninja. Care to post for credit? Also, why wouldn't my installation of `1.0` have made it to the `$PATH`?

Comment: until **Idris** is added to the official Debian distribution, I may need to continue adding symlink/path manually. @kevin-meredith

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where `.cabal` dir is located...

- add an Idris symlink to `/usr/bin`: a text file with the string `/root/.cabal/bin/idris` in it named `idris`. Specific path: `/usr/bin/idris`.
- add a line to the end of your `.bashrc` file: `export PATH="/root/.cabal/bin:$PATH"`

My Linux distro is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.